# Make tells to use std c99 even if I use it

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have tried to write a makefile but make tell me:

```
$ make -f makefile
cc    -c -o source.o source.c
source.c: In function ‘main’:
source.c:5:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
     for(unsigned u = 0; u < 5; u++)
     ^
source.c:5:5: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
make: *** [source.o] Errore 1
```

**source.c** is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (unsigned u = 0; u < 5; u++)
        printf("%u", u);

    int *p;

    if (p == NULL)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

**makefile** is my makefile:

```
all: file

file: source.o
    gcc -std=c99 -g -Wall source.o -o file

source.o: source.c
    gcc -c -std=c99 -g -Wall source.c
```

Why does it tell me to use c99 (or gnu99) even if I putted that argument in the makefile?

Comment: If you look at the output from the `make` command, you see it doesn't actually match the `makefile` you show. Are you sure you're using the correct `makefile`?

Comment: Yes, the one I have posted.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I was using 4 spaces instead of tab..

Comment: On what OS are you? What `make` version are you using? Using GNU make (the default on Linux) would actually give you an error about "missing separators" or similar if you used spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Xubuntu 14.04 LTS, GNU Make 3.81

Comment: Why the question is -2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha. I think I know what your problem is.

The commands in a Makefile must be indented with tab characters, not spaces. You may have to adjust your text editor's settings to make it use "real" tabs here.

(Using spaces will result in the results you've described, where the rules are read but the commands are ignored.)

Comment: That should actually have `make`  fail with errors about that (something about missing separators or similar).

Comment: Interesting... why does make execute command `cc -c -o source.o source.c`, as shown in the question? Is it sort of a default?

Comment: @duskwuff Yes, the problem was that, like I have written in question's comments.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg While I'd agree there certainly *should* be warnings, I didn't see any when I tried running the OP's Makefile myself.

Comment: @lodo Exactly! `make` has built-in rules for certain file extensions. Details for GNU make are at: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html

Answer (score -2):

the output of make shows that C99 mode was  not used to compile the source.
Please add the line

```
CFLAGS=-std=c99 -g -Wall
```

before the destination all

Comment: This does not answer the question: in fact, his makefile does not use the variable `CFLAGS`, so setting it is useless.

Comment: Thanks. However I find the error: I have made a bad indentation, 4 spaces instead of tab...

Comment: Its not make, its the compiler that uses this variable

Comment: @der.Softwerker that's false. That variable is usually defined inside the makefile and used in a command like this: `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o source.o source.cc`